# Apply edits with PHP

Tags: rest, php, arcgis-online, feature-service

I trying to develop a PHP script that will simply applyedits to a feature services.

Right now I'm trying to use the In the ESRI restend point example. I'm thinking if someone can help me, point me to some doc, show me how to use the esri endpoint.  I will be able to take that script learn from it and move from there.  There are several moving parts I'm hoping to accomplish but right now I'm stuck on this piece.

If I hit this esri rest endpoint:

> sampleserver3.arcgisonline.co...r/0/applyEdits

and add these parameters to the add input box

> [{"geometry":{"x":-13085962.2699721,"y":4061306.82523268,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100}},"attributes":{"description":"Test Nat","type":5}},{"geometry":{"x":-13072136.6421672,"y":4073467.58686212,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100}},"attributes":{"description":"klsf","type":0}}]

I can add a feature.

I want to create a simple PHP script that will do this for me.  CAN someone show how to do this?

If I can get this working I'm hoping I can feed the parameters from an xml feed and consistently push data to my rest points. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this should do it. Remind that this is not asynchronous.

```
$adds ='[{"geometry":{"x":-13085962.2699721,"y":4061306.82523268,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100}},"attributes":{"description":"Test Nat","type":5}},{"geometry":{"x":-13072136.6421672,"y":4073467.58686212,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100}},"attributes":{"description":"klsf","type":0}}]';


$postdata = http_build_query(
  array(
    'adds' => $adds,
    'updates'=> 'null',
    'deletes'=>'null',
    'f' => 'json'       
    )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);   
$result = file_get_contents(*YOUR_FS_URL*, false, $context);    
$result2 = json_decode($result,true);/*decode the result as array*/
$result3 = json_decode($result);/*decode the result as object*/

print_r($result2);
```

Hope it helps.